# Probability homework question

Tags: probability

There are 6 of x and 4 of y. A group of 5 is selected. What is the probability of there being 3x and 2 y? I completely forgot how to do this and my textbook doesn't have any information on it.

Comment: @a sandwhich: Have you heard of permutations and combinations (remember the 'C' and 'P' notations?)? It will be of help in this problem. Count the total number of favorable ways and  the total number of ways(using the 'C' 's). The ratio will give you the probability.

Comment: Yes, I have. So would it be  6C3 * 4C2 / 10C5?

Comment: Yes precisely...

Comment: @Sivaram: It would be helpful if you repost the content of your original comment as an answer, so that this question could become "answered."

Comment: @Isaac: I was wondering if I could write out a solution to the homework problem. But anyway a sandwhich figured it out himself. So I guess there is nothing wrong in writing out the answer.

Comment: @Sivaram: An "answer" here doesn't have to be a complete answer.  That is, if you want to avoid giving a complete answer to homework and just give a hint, it's perfectly fine to post the hint as an "answer."  Questions with no upvoted answers are considered "unanswered" and periodically get bumped back to the top of the front page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $6$ $x$'s and $4$ $y$'s. Hence, the total number of $x$'s and $y$'s is $10$.

The total number of ways $5$ of them are selected is $C(10,5)$.

The number of ways of choosing $3$ $x$'s from a pool of $6$ $x$'s is $C(6,3)$. The number of ways of choosing $2$ $y$'s from a pool of $4$ $y$'s is $C(4,2)$.

So the total number of favorable cases is $C(6,3) \times C(4,2)$.

Hence, the probability is $\frac{C(6,3) \times C(4,2)}{C(10,5)} = \frac{10}{21}$